# Trying to modify a functional 'pick' function so that it returns a pick on a modified object for redux immutable map state to props

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, redux, immutability, currying

I am trying to clean up my mapStateToProps, using ramda I can just use r.pick to return a curried function by passing in my desired attrs like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = R.pick(['board', 'nextToken'])
```

Redux will then pass in the state to the returns function.

What I want to do is modify the state first, because my state is an immutable map, so i need to pass pick my state cast as plan js.

I can do this with the following but i am convinced that there is a cleaner way of doing this, functionally. Is it something simple that anybody can see?

```
import {Map} from 'immutable'
import R from 'ramda'

const immutable_state = Map({
    name: 'alice',
    age: 30
})

const pick_from_immutable = (attrs, obj) =>
    // accepts a list of attrs
    // returns a function that accepts an immutable and returns its attrs defined by attrs, also be nice to just return the value if called with an immutable 2nd arg
    obj ?
        R.pick(attrs, obj.toJS()) :
        (imm) => R.pick(attrs, imm.toJS())

const pick_age_from_immutable = pick_from_immutable(['age'])

console.log(pick_age_from_immutable(immutable_state)) // -> { age: 30 }

const mapStateToProps = pick_age_from_immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Immutablejs functions for these kinds of things. It works fine with nested items. But I can see a use case if I am picking age (or some property) in multiple components then I might create a utility function for it.

Example:

```
var a = Map({
    b: Map({
        c: 10
    })
})

// Get value of c in nested a object. Set not found value to null.
var valueOfC = a.getIn(['b', 'c'], null)
```